# Reflection - Java - Get Type of Generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types

```
public class superA<TypeX> {
    public superA(){
        TypeX var1 = new .......
    }
}
```

Imagine the above code, how do I find the type of TypeX if I wish to create a variable of that type before I receive any other information in the constructor?

Comment: You can't use it like that. At runtime generic types are [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You will have to pass some Class or actual object of TypeX to get information about its class and then (with little help of reflection) create new instance.

Comment: Just to complement @Pshemo 's comment, write your method like this: `public superA(Class clazz)` and then use this `clazz` object and reflection to create your new object

Comment: @Pshemo - You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Pshemo, I've come to the same conclusion, I was hoping for something like in C#, where you can extract the class object just to verify, like for example "TypeX.class == String.class"

Comment: @morgano, but even then it has to be passed explicitly, as I mentioned in my previous comment I am trying to make the code understand the class by comparing a few predefined types.